# How to cast String column to List

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

My dataframe looks like this:

[image]

df.schema results in:

```
StructType(
    StructField(a,StringType,true), 
    StructField(b,StringType,true), 
    StructField(c,IntegerType,true), 
    StructField(d,StringType,true)
)
```

I want to cast column `b` to a List of Ints and column `d` to List of Strings. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Strip `[]` and split on `,`:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val p = "^\\[(.*)\\]$"

df
  .withColumn("b", split(regexp_extract(col("b"), p, 1), "\\s*,\\s*").cast("array<int>"))
  .withColumn("d", split(regexp_extract(col("d"), p, 1), "\\s*,\\s*"))
```